# Manifolds as simultaneous coset spaces

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, group-actions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be real manifolds.  Under what conditions is there a Lie group $G$ with transitive actions on $X$ and $Y$ such that the stabiliser of a point in $X$ is a subgroup of the stabiliser of a point in $Y$ and both are themselves Lie groups?

Equivalently, what conditions need to be satisfied by $X$ and $Y$ for it to be possible to realise $X$ and $Y$ as simultaneous coset spaces $G/H_1$ and $G/H_2$ of $G$ with $H_1\leq H_2$?

This question is related: [Simultaneous coset spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226690/simultaneous-coset-spaces).

Comment: Do you want $G$ to be finite-dimensional? If not, I suspect that the condition is simply that $X$ be a fiber bundle over $Y$, with $G$ the group of diffeomorphisms of $X$ taking fibers to fibers.

Comment: I think I do need $G$ to be finite-dimensional, but your idea is interesting nonetheless.  Do you know if the fibre bundle condition is necessary as well as sufficient?

Comment: If your assertion is satisfied, then you automatically get a map $X=G/H_1\twoheadrightarrow G/H_2=Y$ sending $gx$ to $gy$, where $x$ has stabiliser $H_1$ and $y$ has stabiliser $H_2$. In the finite-dimensional case, this map is automatically locally trivial, that is, a fibre bundle. On the other hand, there are manifolds that do not admit transitive actions by finite-dimensional Lie groups, so the fibre bundle condition alone is not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sebastian.  Why is the map locally trivial in the finite-dimensional case?  I'm not worried about $X$ and $Y$ being manifolds that don't admit transitive actions by Lie groups since I am assuming that $X$ and $Y$ do.  (I should point out that my definition of a [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) is based on my definition of a [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold), which only allows finite-dimensional manifolds.)

Comment: The existence a $G$-equivariant map $F:X\to Y$, namely, one such that $F(gx)=gF(x)$ for all $g\in G$, $x\in X$, is a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: After thinking about the motivation of this question for a while, I guess that among the various equivalent conditions that there might be, the one that $H_1\le H_2$ is probably the easiest to check in practice. Of course I assume that we know what $G$ is and how $G$ acts. If this is not the case, please give some motivation, so one can understand what kind of description you are looking for.